# Injecting View Model Values into JavaScript Without Warnings

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a project calendar, written in JavaScript, that when rendered requires the starting month and year as parameters.  In my `cshtml` file I have the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Content/js/ProjectCalendar/projectCalendar.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        window.projectCalendar.renderMiniCalendar(@Model.Month, @Model.Year);
    });
</script>
```

However the part where I'm injecting in the month and year is picked up in the Visual Studio error list as a `Syntax error`.  This is because without the values being injected, the line would read:

```
window.projectCalendar.renderMiniCalendar(, );
```

Does anyone know of a cleaner way that I can pass values from my view model into JavaScript that doesn't cause warnings in the error list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
window.projectCalendar.renderMiniCalendar('@Model.Month', '@Model.Year');
```

Comment: Thanks, I'd thought of maybe trying this, but didn't want JavaScript to infer that the values passed in are strings.  Will passing the values in as strings cause any adverse effects, or will JavaScript automatically compensate when I start using the values as integers?

Comment: I've just tried your solution in my code and it appears to work side-effect free.  Thank you.